# how should I test method that does not return anything?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, ui-testing

This is the code from my recent tool I have made, I am trying to write unittest, I have an [idea of how to test a method that returns something](https://github.com/sanfx/slideShow/blob/master/tests/test_utils.py) but don't understand how should i test method that don't like below:

```
def buildUi(self):
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel()
    self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

def nextImage(self):
    """ switch to next image or previous image
    """
    if self._imagesInList:
        if self._count == len(self._imagesInList):
            self._count = 0

        self.showImageByPath(
                self._imagesInList[self._count])

        if self.animFlag:
            self._count += 1
        else:
            self._count -= 1


def showImageByPath(self, path):
    if path:
        image = QtGui.QImage(path)
        pp = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.label.setPixmap(pp.scaled(
                self.label.size(),
                QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation))

def playPause(self):
    if not self._pause:
        self._pause = True
        self.updateTimer.start(2500)
        return self._pause
    else:
        self._pause = False
        self.updateTimer.stop()

def keyPressEvent(self, keyevent):
    """ Capture key to exit, next image, previous image,
        on Escape , Key Right and key left respectively.
    """
    event = keyevent.key()
    if event == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
        self.close()
    if event == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
        self.animFlag = False
        self.nextImage()
    if event == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
        self.animFlag = True
        self.nextImage()
    if event == 32:
        self._pause = self.playPause()
```

the complete code for looking can be found [here](https://github.com/sanfx/slideShow/blob/master/python/slideShow.py)

is it possible to test these methods above or do I have to modify to make them testable ?
Edit: updated:

```
class TestSlideShow(unittest.TestCase):
    """ docstring for TestSlideShow
    """
    def setUp(self):
        self.mox = mox.Mox()
        self.imgLst = ['/folder/test/images/test1.jpg', '/folder/test/images/test2.JPG',
        '/folder/test/images/test3.png', '/folder/test/images/test4.PNG']
        app = QtGui.QApplication([])
        self.show = slideShow.SlideShowPics(imgLst=self.imgLst, ui=False)

def tearDown(self):
    self.mox.UnsetStubs()
    self.mox.ResetAll()

def test_nextImage(self):
    self.mox.StubOutWithMock(self.show, 'prepairWindow')
    self.show.prepairWindow()
    self.mox.StubOutWithMock(self.show, 'showImageByPath')
    self.show.showImageByPath(self.imgLst[1])
    self.show.nextImage()
    # self.mox.ReplayAll()
    self.assertEquals(1, self.show.count)
    self.assertEquals(self.imgLst[1], self.show._imagesInList[1])
    # self.mox.VerifyAll()

def test_nextImage_animFlag_False(self):
    self.show.animFlag = False
    self.show.count = 4

    self.mox.StubOutWithMock(self.show, 'prepairWindow')
    self.show.prepairWindow()
    self.mox.StubOutWithMock(self.show, 'showImageByPath')
    self.show.showImageByPath(self.imgLst[3])
    print self.show.count
    self.show.nextImage()
    print self.show.count       
    # self.assertEquals(3, self.show.count)
    self.assertEquals(self.imgLst[3], self.show._imagesInList[3])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

the first test when self.show.animFlag is True works fine and but the when I manually set the animFlag= False then second test fails.

Comment: Although the functions do not return anything, they actually do something ; ) and that's what you want to test. You create an object (e.g. a mock object), call the function which affects that object and then you examine it and check if everything went as expected.

Comment: have a look at mocks and stubs http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/

Comment: @User : I want to do it using mox.

Comment: @septi Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem with writing unittest after the code - you then realize your code is difficult to test. Writing the tests before the code (well, really "along" the code - you don't write *all* tests before start coding, but still you dont write a line of code before you have a test for it) makes sure you don't have such a problem.

Now even with the "test first" approach you do have to test methods that don't return anything. The way to do so is to test for the expected side effects. Some of these side effects are easy to test - in your above case, you can test the value of `self._count` before and after the call to `nextImage`, depending on your object's state (`_imagesInList` and `animFlag` mostly). Where it gets more difficult is if you want to test that `nextImage` does actually call `showImageByPath` with the correct arguments, and with your current design the only way to do so is to monkeypatch `showImageByPath` for the tests. Testing `showImageByPath` will require patching / mocking `self.label.setPixmap()`, etc.

As others already pointed there are a couple mock/stub libs that can help, but they won't solve all possible testability issues and you may have to rethink your design to make things easier - like not hardcoding  the call to `QtGui.QLabel()` in `buildUI()` but have some way to "inject" the desired componant (`QtGui.QLabel()` or a mock) instead. As a general rule, testable code has very few hard-coded dependencies, few side effects, and lot of small classes with short methods (instead of huge classes with long methods).

Comment: I can mock `showImageByPath` in `nextImage`, however I didn't understood what you meant by _not hardcoding the call to QtGui.QLabel() in buildUI()_ and also what does the term side effects refer to in testing ?

Comment: @san Side effects of a function are ways it changes the state of the program in ways other than returning a value. For instance, `def f(): global x; x += 1; return x * 5` would have the side effect of adding 1 to `x`. It is often preferable to avoid them in Python.

Comment: @san: wrt/ side effects, I was mainly thinking of the fact that your methods do change the instance's state or build objects or call other objects methods etc. If a method is supposed to change your object's state in a given way, you can test that the object's state is what you expect after the method call.

Comment: @san: wrt/ harcoding, it's plain and simple: the component name `QtGui.QLabel` is written in plain letters in `buildUI`, so you cannot make `buildUI` instanciate another component instead - well, this is Python so you actually still can monkeypatch your whole environment to make `QtGui.QLabel` point to something else, but it would be way simpler if you passed you class some other "UIBuilder" object that would provide the exepected components, and use either a `QtUIBuilder` for production or some `MockUIBuilder` for testing. This is called "dependency injection".